# I am getting this PHP error from signing this contract form

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

I found out how to get to it, I just don't know why I'm getting this error all of a sudden. It seems to work on Chrome, however on the old internet explorer it gave me the following error.

> Warning: Imageline() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in /home/busoneinc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gravityformsignature/includes/super_signature/license.php on line 1

This is the code:

```
<?php
$igkrwu_0 = 300;
$rhncls_1 = 200;
$hzwrws_2 = 4;
$qdfrcu_3;
$uooxsm_4;
$qpgifq_5 = False;
$ijcski_6 = 0;
$uyagdp_7 = '';

function GetSignatureImageSmooth($lwqrol_8)
{
    if (1 == 1) {
        if (strlen($lwqrol_8) > 0) {
            $lwqrol_8 = str_replace(base64_decode('ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9wbmc7YmFzZTY0LA==') , '', $lwqrol_8);
            $lwqrol_8 = str_replace(base64_decode('IA==') , base64_decode('Kw==') , $lwqrol_8);
            $snasbp_9 = base64_decode($lwqrol_8);
            $yjyqwd_10 = imagecreatefromstring($snasbp_9);
            return $yjyqwd_10;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function GetSignatureImage($spqwzr_11)
{
    $enaysr_12 = base64_decode($spqwzr_11);
    if (1 == 1) {
        $jibrxv_13 = explode(base64_decode('Ow==') , $enaysr_12);
        $ahpyui_14 = explode(base64_decode('LA==') , $jibrxv_13[0]);
        if (count($ahpyui_14) == 8) {
            $qdfrcu_3 = Html2RGB($ahpyui_14[1]);
            $igkrwu_0 = $ahpyui_14[3];
            $rhncls_1 = $ahpyui_14[4];
            $qpgifq_5 = strtoupper($ahpyui_14[5]);
            $ijcski_6 = (integer)$ahpyui_14[6];
            $uyagdp_7 = $ahpyui_14[7];
            $yjyqwd_10 = imagecreatetruecolor($igkrwu_0, $rhncls_1);
            $pshzfj_15 = imagecolorallocate($yjyqwd_10, $qdfrcu_3[0], $qdfrcu_3[1], $qdfrcu_3[2]);
            imagefill($yjyqwd_10, 0, 0, $pshzfj_15);
            if ($qpgifq_5 == base64_decode('VFJVRQ==')) {
                imagecolortransparent($yjyqwd_10, $pshzfj_15);
            }

            for ($zumudw_16 = 1; $zumudw_16 < count($jibrxv_13); $zumudw_16++) {
                if (strlen($jibrxv_13[$zumudw_16]) > 0) {
                    $dmqeif_17 = explode(base64_decode('IA==') , trim($jibrxv_13[$zumudw_16]));
                    $bkgzoa_18 = explode(base64_decode('LA==') , $dmqeif_17[0]);
                    $hzwrws_2 = $bkgzoa_18[0];
                    $uooxsm_4 = Html2RGB($bkgzoa_18[1]);
                    $vuinxy_19 = imagecolorallocate($yjyqwd_10, $uooxsm_4[0], $uooxsm_4[1], $uooxsm_4[2]);
                    if (count($dmqeif_17) == 2) {
                        $umkucn_20 = explode(base64_decode('LA==') , trim($dmqeif_17[1]));
                        ImageFilledArc($yjyqwd_10, $umkucn_20[0], $umkucn_20[1], 2 * $hzwrws_2, 2 * $hzwrws_2, 0, 360, $vuinxy_19, IMG_ARC_PIE);
                    }
                    else {
                        for ($puihwm_21 = 1; $puihwm_21 < count($dmqeif_17) - 1; $puihwm_21++) {
                            $umkucn_20 = explode(base64_decode('LA==') , trim($dmqeif_17[$puihwm_21]));
                            $kkgkso_22 = explode(base64_decode('LA==') , trim($dmqeif_17[$puihwm_21 + 1]));
                            imgdrawLine($yjyqwd_10, $umkucn_20[0], $umkucn_20[1], $kkgkso_22[0], $kkgkso_22[1], $vuinxy_19, $hzwrws_2);
                            imgdrawLine($yjyqwd_10, $umkucn_20[0], $umkucn_20[1], $kkgkso_22[0], $kkgkso_22[1], $vuinxy_19, $hzwrws_2 + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return $yjyqwd_10;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function imgdrawLine($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24, $ascwxa_25, $ymizci_26, $dydbei_27, $jbffey_28, $mvqkzd_29)
{
    if ($avduwn_24 == null || $ascwxa_25 == null) return;
    if ($ymizci_26 == null || $dydbei_27 == null) return;
    $mvqkzd_29 = abs($mvqkzd_29 / 2);
    $vvwowy_30 = 1 - $mvqkzd_29;
    $jcckim_31 = 1;
    $jyxqyk_32 = - 2 * $mvqkzd_29;
    $mkobsf_33 = 0;
    $xvbdhp_34 = $mvqkzd_29;
    imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24, $ascwxa_25 + $mvqkzd_29, $ymizci_26, $dydbei_27 + $mvqkzd_29, $jbffey_28);
    imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24, $ascwxa_25 - $mvqkzd_29, $ymizci_26, $dydbei_27 - $mvqkzd_29, $jbffey_28);
    imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 + $mvqkzd_29, $ascwxa_25, $ymizci_26 + $mvqkzd_29, $dydbei_27, $jbffey_28);
    imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 - $mvqkzd_29, $ascwxa_25, $ymizci_26 - $mvqkzd_29, $dydbei_27, $jbffey_28);
    while ($mkobsf_33 < $xvbdhp_34) {
        if ($vvwowy_30 >= 0) {
            $xvbdhp_34--;
            $jyxqyk_32+= 2;
            $vvwowy_30+= $jyxqyk_32;
        }

        $mkobsf_33++;
        $jcckim_31+= 2;
        $vvwowy_30+= $jcckim_31;
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 + $mkobsf_33, $ascwxa_25 + $xvbdhp_34, $ymizci_26 + $mkobsf_33, $dydbei_27 + $xvbdhp_34, $jbffey_28);
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 - $mkobsf_33, $ascwxa_25 + $xvbdhp_34, $ymizci_26 - $mkobsf_33, $dydbei_27 + $xvbdhp_34, $jbffey_28);
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 + $mkobsf_33, $ascwxa_25 - $xvbdhp_34, $ymizci_26 + $mkobsf_33, $dydbei_27 - $xvbdhp_34, $jbffey_28);
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 - $mkobsf_33, $ascwxa_25 - $xvbdhp_34, $ymizci_26 - $mkobsf_33, $dydbei_27 - $xvbdhp_34, $jbffey_28);
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 + $xvbdhp_34, $ascwxa_25 + $mkobsf_33, $ymizci_26 + $xvbdhp_34, $dydbei_27 + $mkobsf_33, $jbffey_28);
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 - $xvbdhp_34, $ascwxa_25 + $mkobsf_33, $ymizci_26 - $xvbdhp_34, $dydbei_27 + $mkobsf_33, $jbffey_28);
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 + $xvbdhp_34, $ascwxa_25 - $mkobsf_33, $ymizci_26 + $xvbdhp_34, $dydbei_27 - $mkobsf_33, $jbffey_28);
        imageline($ogikuy_23, $avduwn_24 - $xvbdhp_34, $ascwxa_25 - $mkobsf_33, $ymizci_26 - $xvbdhp_34, $dydbei_27 - $mkobsf_33, $jbffey_28);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('Html2RGB')) {
    function Html2RGB($jbffey_28)
    {
        if ($jbffey_28[0] == base64_decode('Iw==')) $jbffey_28 = substr($jbffey_28, 1);
        if (strlen($jbffey_28) == 6) list($frcbwh_35, $vcbacu_36, $yutzyb_37) = array(
            $jbffey_28[0] . $jbffey_28[1],
            $jbffey_28[2] . $jbffey_28[3],
            $jbffey_28[4] . $jbffey_28[5]
        );
        elseif (strlen($jbffey_28) == 3) list($frcbwh_35, $vcbacu_36, $yutzyb_37) = array(
            $jbffey_28[0] . $jbffey_28[0],
            $jbffey_28[1] . $jbffey_28[1],
            $jbffey_28[2] . $jbffey_28[2]
        );
        else return false;
        $frcbwh_35 = hexdec($frcbwh_35);
        $vcbacu_36 = hexdec($vcbacu_36);
        $yutzyb_37 = hexdec($yutzyb_37);
        return array(
            $frcbwh_35,
            $vcbacu_36,
            $yutzyb_37
        );
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: One of your imageline() are failing. Long is a numeric. String is being sent in.

Comment: What is `$ascwxa_25` and `$mvqkzd_29`? If they're both numbers, try casting them to ints or floats.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, it was enough just to skip lines with bad values

In function imgdrawLine replace first two lines with:

```
if ($avduwn_24 == null || $ascwxa_25 == null || !is_numeric($avduwn_24) || !is_numeric($ascwxa_25))
    return;
if ($ymizci_26 == null || $dydbei_27 == null || !is_numeric($ymizci_26) || !is_numeric($dydbei_27))
    return;
```